# configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'setting' PS C:\Users\p>

Tags: python, ini

a.ini

```
    [setting]
    a = 5
```

main.py

```
    from configparser import ConfigParser
    
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read('a.ini')
    
    print(config.sections())
    print(config.items('setting'))
    print(config.items('setting')('a'))
```

ERROR

> PS C:\Users\p> &
> C:/Users/p/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe
> c:/101/main.py [] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser.py",
> line 846, in items
> d.update(self._sections[section]) KeyError: 'setting'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:/101/main.py", line 7, in
>
> print(config.items('setting'))   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser.py",
> line 849, in items
> raise NoSectionError(section) configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'setting' PS C:\Users\p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when ran the program from different location. In that your program will be looking into the same path that you are in for the `a.ini` file.

- Make sure you are inside the directory which has the `a.ini` file.
- Or a better way would be use `os, sys` to find the path for you in runtime.
  So that you can run your program from anywhere.

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os, sys
    
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'a.ini'))

print(config.sections())
print(config.items('setting'))
print(config['setting']['a'])
```